# Create widgets in footer.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've googled around quite a lot, but can't seem to find where I should be saving the code for the widget I've created. It's a bit baffling.

Can anyone tell me where I should save my widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the steps below

**1. Register the footer widget area**

Open the functions.php file from the WordPress Theme Editor and search for the following line of code:

register_sidebar

That should take you to the area where all the sidebars are registered in your theme.

Add the following block of code just below the other sidebar registration code (we are telling it to register 3 footer widget areas):

```
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 1',
'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1',
'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</aside>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 2',
'id' => 'footer-sidebar-2',
'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</aside>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 3',
'id' => 'footer-sidebar-3',
'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</aside>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

**2. Show the footer widget area in your theme**

Open your footer.php file and insert the following block of code where you want to show the footer widgets (this will show the 3 footer widget areas if they have any widgets in them):

```
<div id="footer-sidebar" class="secondary">
<div id="footer-sidebar1">
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
}
?>
</div>
<div id="footer-sidebar2">
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-2')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-2');
}
?>
</div>
<div id="footer-sidebar3">
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-3')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-3');
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

**3. Style the footer widget area to your liking**

Add the following block of CSS code to your theme’s style.css file to add some basic styling to the footer widgets you just added. Customize it a little to match your needs. Our [how to use firebug](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-use-firebug-to-modify-your-wordpress-sites-css-video-tutorial-4037) tutorial should come in handy for this.

```
#footer-sidebar {
display:block;
height: 250px;
}

#footer-sidebar1 {
float: left;
width: 340px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}

#footer-sidebar2 {
float: left;
width: 340px;
margin-right:5px;
}

#footer-sidebar3 {
float: left;
width: 340px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have googled for dancing cats... First link in google [`WordPress Create widget tutorial`](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-wordpress-widgets/)

*Start by creating a new .php file in your **wp-content/plugins** directory.*

Comment: Hahaha, great answer. Couldn't agree more. +1

Answer (score 0):

add this code in function.php

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {


    register_sidebar(array('name' => 'footer1', 
                           'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                           'after_widget'  => '</div>', 
                           'before_title'  => '<h4>', 'after_title'   => '</h4>'
                            )
                    );


register_sidebar(array('name' => 'footer2', 
                           'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                           'after_widget'  => '</div>', 
                           'before_title'  => '<h4>', 'after_title'   => '</h4>'
                            )
                    );

}
```

add this code in footer.php file

```
  <?php   dynamic_sidebar('footer1') ; ?>    

  <?php   dynamic_sidebar('footer2') ; ?>
```